# Disable See More popup on Facebook pages

Tags: facebook

When not logged in, Facebook shows these annoying popups on pages after scrolling the page a bit. First a fullscreen one, then one on the bottom. Has anyone found a way to prevent them from showing? I can't block them with AdBlock because the div class changes for every page.

[image] [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, you can. Here is your filter:

- facebook.com##div#pagelet_growth_expanding_cta

Facebook programmers suck for putting in this nag screen, it is a recent addition.

Answer (score -2):

for those using Stylish, i just put the filter into a style:

https://userstyles.org/styles/141841/facebook-hide-login-popup